# For the NEON coding for ARM Arch64,How do you push the registers to the stack??Seems like STMFD is not a part of the instruction set on Arch64?

Tags: arm, 64-bit, neon, embedded-v8

For the NEON coding for ARM Arch64,How do you push the registers to the stack??Seems like STMFD is not a part of the instruction set on Arch64?Do you just save the register pairs on to the stack one by one?

Comment: In situations like this I normally just see how the compiler does it by having it generate assembly, using the `-S` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AArch64 designers deliberately removed the `STM`/`LDM` instructions, presumably to simplify instruction scheduling and fault handling.

> 3.5 Memory Load-Store
>   3.5.1 Bulk Transfers
>
> The LDM, STM, PUSH and POP instructions do not exist in A64, however bulk transfers can be constructed using the LDP
>   and STP instructions which load and store a pair of independent
>   registers from consecutive memory locations, and which support
>   unaligned addresses when accessing normal memory. The LDNP and STNP
>   instructions additionally provide a “streaming” or ”non-temporal” hint
>   that the data does not need to be retained in caches. The PRFM
>   (prefetch memory) instructions also include hints for “streaming” or
>   “non-temporal” accesses, and allow targeting of a prefetch to a
>   specific cache level.

(from [ARMv8 ISA Overview](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.genc010197a/index.html))

So yes, you're supposed to use multiple `STP`/`LDP` instructions instead.

Comment: But this code "linux/arch/arm64/kvm/hyp.S" is making use of push and pop instruction which is part of AARCH64.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar seems like GNU assembler extension to me. it's probably translated into stp/ldp. Try assembling and disassembling it.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to push/pop a full V register to/from the stack? `STP` and `LDP` take 2 64-bit registers, but NEON V registers are 128 bit.

Comment: I would be interested to see such example too.

Comment: @gregoiregentil @SergeRogatch  from a random executable I had lying around: `STP  D9, D8, [SP,#-0x10]!`. I guess to save a full Qn you'd first have to move the top half into a separate D register but since the ABI only requires the D regs preserved (see  IHI0055B) that's not usually a problem.